# Get for each client account charges/adjustments starting from specific posting date in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get for each client account balance of charges and adjustments  starting from specified posting date till current date. There is service date `svc_date` meaning the date of service and posting date `post_date` meaning the date when the charge/adjustment was posted.

Here is my output:

| cl_id | svc_date | post_date | tot_pay_ adj_amt | cl_bal_amt | tot_bal_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001386456 | 2021/05/04 | 2021/05/04 | 0.00 | 662.00 | 662.00 |
| 001386456 | 2021/09/17 | 2021/09/17 | 0.00 | 43162.09 | 43162.09 |
| 001725900 | 2021/01/12 | 2021/01/15 | 0.00 | 662.00 | 662.00 |
| 001725900 | 2021/04/20 | 2021/07/20 | 0.00 | 43162.09 | 43162.09 |
| 001475300 | 2021/08/27 | 2021/08/27 | 0.00 | 662.00 | 662.00 |

the desired output

| cl_id | svc_date | post_date | tot_pay_ adj_amt | cl_bal_amt | tot_bal_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001386456 | 2021/05/04 | 2021/05/04 | - 40.50 | 662.00 | 662.00 |
| 001386456 | 2021/09/17 | 2021/09/17 | 20.08 | 1384.00 | 4672.00 |
| 001725900 | 2021/01/12 | 2021/01/15 | 32.16 | 18.57 | 3500.00 |
| 001725900 | 2021/04/20 | 2021/07/20 | 48.97 | 4316.34 | 869.00 |
| 001475300 | 2021/08/27 | 2021/08/27 | 32.17 | 513.40 | 544.00 |

And my code:

```
WITH a
AS (
    SELECT p.orgz_cd
        , p.cl_id
        , p.cl_acct_type
        , p.svc_date
        , p.post_date
        , CASE WHEN (p.svc_date <= p.post_date and p.post_date = 
         LAG(p.post_date)
         OVER (ORDER BY p.post_date)) THEN SUM(p.tot_pay_adj_amt) OVER  
         (PARTITION BY 
         p.cl_id,p.post_date ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
         ELSE p.tot_pay_adj_amt  END tot_pay_adj_amt
        , CASE WHEN (p.svc_date <= p.post_date and p.post_date = 
         LAG(p.post_date) OVER (ORDER BY p.post_date)) THEN 
         SUM(vr.cl_bal_amt) OVER  (PARTITION BY 
         p.cl_id,p.post_date ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
         ELSE vr.pt_bal_amt END cl_bal_amt
        , CASE WHEN (p.svc_date <= p.post_date and p.post_date = 
         LAG(p.post_date) OVER (ORDER BY p.post_date)) THEN 
         SUM(vr.tot_bal_amt) OVER  (PARTITION BY 
         p.cl_id,p.post_date ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
         ELSE vr.tot_bal_amt END tot_bal_amt
     FROM mstr_trans_code AS p
     LEFT JOIN  mstr_client_code AS vr ON vr.src_sys_id = p.src_sys_id
      )                    
 SELECT a.orgz_cd
    , a.cl_id
    , a.svc_date
    , a.post_date
    , a.tot_pay_adj_amt
    , a.cl_bal_amt
    , a.tot_bal_amt
FROM a
ORDER BY a.orgz_cd,a.cl_id, a.post_date desc;
```

The result should show for each `cl_id` for each `post_date` amount of charges and adjustments for this `post_date` in the `tot_pay_adj_amt`, `cl_bal_amt`, `tot_bal_amt` fields. The desired output should show the data for each account with one row for one `post_date`, if there is more than one transaction at one `post_date` the values should be summarized, for next `post_date` the values should be summarized in the second row, etc. I get for some reason some strange amounts that are the same for all the dates. Can anybody help?

Comment: not sure how to add my output example, copy-paste is not working, sorry, I am new on this site

Comment: Thank you for suggestion Dale, I added indentation but apparently not the right way

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Use of DISTINCT is often a kludge to "fix" a query that is logically flawed. So start by removing that. You have temp tables with names that carry no meaning - you need to help everyone understand your tables, what they represent, and what a row in your resultset represents. Do you want one row per "account transaction"? And I suggest you start by removing everything that is not essential to the issue. Let's focus on just one of the sums and get that working.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dale, for your help with formatting issues. Good lesson for me

Comment: SMor, thank you for suggestions. I sued DISTINCT to avoid duplicated rows, will use meaningful table names as well. I want one row per "account transaction" for each post _date

Comment: Having a desired output is an improvement, but we also need the sample data that would produce that desired output. And as already asked we need a [mre] with emphasis in *minimal* so you cut down the data and query to the simplest form that demonstrates your issue.